# time Function not working if using external js file or dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The codes are working absolutely fine if using on w3school or with any online editor.
But not working if using with external js file or with dreamweaver.
I tried on dreamweaver and it is giving error unexpected token var.
I also tried with adding "$(" in start and ");" in the end of script also used "onload = addZero();" but, no luck.

pls help to find what am I missing.
just need the date and in this format 28-06-2021 05:30:04

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
        
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iu_e5LCa4aQn18zDylqkXZLy6dIZeNvH/view?usp=sharing"></script>
        
    </head>
    
          <div class="right">
             <p id="p1"></p>
          </div>
       
    <body>
        <table id="mainTable" class="tg">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th class="tg-hdrstock">STOCK</th>
                   <th class="tg-hdrdate">DATE</th>
                   </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="mySearch">
                <tr>
                   <td class="tg-stock">NMDC</td>
                   <td class="tg-date">26-May-21</td>
                               </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td class="tg-stock">TITAN</td>
                   <td class="tg-date">27-May-21</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
    </table>
    
    
    <script>
    function addZero(number) {
       return number.toString().length === 1 ? `0${number}` : number;
       }
        var today = new Date();
            var date = addZero(today.getDate())+'-'+addZero(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + addZero(today.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(today.getSeconds());
       var dateTime = date+' '+time;
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = dateTime;
       
       addZero();
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in  window.load listener/handler. This is to ensure it doesn't try to find the `p#p1` element before the page has finished rendering.

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       function addZero(number) {
         return number.toString().length === 1 ? `0${number}` : number;
       }
       var today = new Date();
       var date = addZero(today.getDate())+'-'+addZero(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
       var time = today.getHours() + ":" + addZero(today.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(today.getSeconds());
       var dateTime = date+' '+time;
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = dateTime;
       addZero();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it worked.
i am just at learning stage, could you pls let me know in simple english what was the issue.? is it all about steps series in right way??

Comment: Yes, think of it this way. Usually you put your javascript at the top of your page, like in some `<script>` tag. That script tag processes immediately and anything in that script that isn't wrapped in a function will execute. In your case, the script ran and was looking for an element `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = dateTime` before the actual HTML page had rendered. By putting all that code in the window.load listener, you're telling javascript to run the code AFTER the HTML has been rendered. Yes, its all about things happening in a certain sequence

Comment: thanks much appreciated and I also googled it,
one more question.
i have more than 10 other functions which are working fine.
Should I use Event lister with them too?? can they also react in same way as i faced issue with previous one??

Comment: This method is only required when you are calling functions immediately before the page loads... and then only if those functions try to access an HTML element, like in this example

Comment: understood a bit but not completely as you said before the page loads. 
all my functions are implemented on html table values , like to make red green for negative and positive values, to make values in 0 or 2 decimal and etc

Comment: What many people do is put all their css links in the head of the page (loading first), then all the scripts at the bottom of the page, right before `</body>` - it removes any worry that things will execute before the page is ready

Comment: for css its understandable as the css will load first and javascript will work after.
but relating to html table data and external js, it looks I am compelled to use event listener.

Comment: Sorry, I got it as I read last comment thoroughly.
will try tomorrow adding js link in last and look the result.
A Thumbs Up for providing me such unforgettable learning.

Comment: Here's how I would proceed. In all your script files, you'll have functions and you _might_ also have inline code that just executes as soon as that .js file is read. Anything that fits that description (the code that executes immediately) should probably go into the window.load event listener to be safe